# submenu is cutting off when I apply a scroll to the principal menu in primeng angular

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I am trying to achieve scrollable menu with sub-menus. I used `tieredMenu` from primeng version 8 and angular 8.
The problem is that the sub-menu is hidden or cut off when I put scroll to the principal menu.

Here is what I have a simple code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cyvv7d

For reference, HTML:

```
  <div class="scroll-width-perso">
    <p-tieredMenu [model]="items"></p-tieredMenu>
  </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.app-scroll-perso {
  max-height: 30vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  width: 250px;
}
```

and TypeScript file :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {MenuItem} from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  title = 'test menu with scroll';


   items: MenuItem[];

   ngOnInit() {
        this.items = [
            {
                label: 'File',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-pencil',
                items: [
                    {label: 'Delete', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-trash'},
                    {label: 'Refresh', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-refresh'},
                    {label: 'save', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-refresh'},
                    {label: 'modify', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-refresh'},
                    {label: 'nothing', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-refresh'}
                ]
            },
            {
                label: 'encouragment',
                icon: 'pi pi-briefcase'
            },
            {
                label: 'primeng',
                icon: 'pi pi-save'
            },
            {
                label: 'contact',
                icon: 'pi pi-cloud-upload'
            },
            {
                label: 'Edit',
                icon: 'pi pi-tags'
            },
            {
                label: 'user',
                icon: 'pi pi-user',
                items: [
                    {label: 'Delete', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-trash'},
                    {label: 'Refresh', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-refresh'},
                    {label: 'save', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-refresh'},
                    {label: 'modify', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-refresh'},
                    {label: 'nothing', icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-refresh'}
                ]
            },
            {
                label: 'blog',
                icon: 'pi pi-fw pi-pencil'
            }
        ];
    }
}
```

The principal menu have a fixed height. I should add a scroll.
And the submenu is hidden when the scroll is added. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: It's actually a bad design, this is what I think.

Comment: my menu have a fixed width. and this is just an example and i modified a width just to show a submenu how it is hidden. but in my application i menu showed is a principale and when you hover to one item if this item have a submenu will be show. if you want to know my problem you can remove css to unterstand my issue